# How should http 202 HTTP_ACCEPTED be handled in Square Retrofit / OkHttp implementation

Tags: android, network-programming, retrofit, http-status-codes, okhttp

It doesn't seem like Retrofit or OkHttp handles 202 status code where an async operation has been accepted but not completed. Should I be polling if I see a 202? or do I follow the provided status monitor URL? But then I cannot utilize retrofit to follow the status URL since I cannot know what it is ahead of time, so I would have to implement it. Is that right?